# Task Manager shows only 50% of RAM usage

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory

My computer has 8GB RAM, but the Task Manager shows me processes % of 4GB only, i.e. Google Chrome uses 457MB and the Task Manager shows that is 11.3% of the RAM and that means 100% is about 4GB??

[image: Task Manager usage]

I'm using Windows 10 and these are some of my specs:

[image: A screenshot of some of my specs.]

I checked the Resource Monitor and it shows me that there are 3221MB cached. Is that normal? and how to fix it?

[image: A screenshot of the Resource Monitor and RAM map.]

Comment: There is absolutely nothing strange about your memory usage.  You have nearly 5 GB available immediately if an application needs it.

Comment: The computer becomes slower and kinda laggy when the percentage gets higher than 80% while that is 4GB only? does the percentage include the cached amount of ram or what's happening in this case?

Comment: Unless you are getting messages about low memory (virtual memory), the slowness your encountering, isn’t caused by your memory usage.  You are not showing every process that is running on your system in Task Manager, and services on your system, use more memory. RAMMap shows your true memory usage

Comment: “there are 3221 MB cached? Is that normal?” – Yes. You absolutely want as much cached data as possible. Cached data is immediately discarded when applications require more RAM.

Comment: Also, about your misconception with 4 GiB or whatever: You cannot see all processes and all types of memory usage in the “Processes” tab of Task Manager. It is normal for these values to not add up.

Comment: @MahmoudAhmed That's normal. When the working set size gets closed to, or exceeds, the amount of available memory, the system will get slow because disk I/O increases. This is true regardless of how much memory is used for processes and how much is used for cache. Squeezing the cache means more disk I/O is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your first image shows your task manager at 100% disk usage and 46%-52% memory usage. Memory isn't an issue here. Your computer should work fine even if it passes 50%. It doesn't start showing issues until it goes over 80 (like you said.) The 100% means all 8GB is being used and this can slow your computer down to the point where it constantly freezes. I'm not sure why RAM is shown as a percentage, but Chrome is only using 457MB out of the 8GB you currently have. At least, that what it should be doing.

Although, I would currently focus on lowering your disk usage since it is at 100%. This is bad on HDDs and can cause issues in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

#### Explaination

The `Task Manager` detect exactly 8GB RAM, as I thought. However, it seems that it detect memory percentage of only `Memory In Use`.

That's to say, the percentage of 11% is based on used memory 4.1G,

#### Computations

Here is some computations with Chrome as the example.

In `Task Manager`, chrome-mem = 457 MB ~ 11.3% -> Total **Used Mem** = 457M / 11.3% ~ 4044MB.
In `Resource Monitor`, chrome-mem ~ 457MB(sum), **Used Mem** = 3515+601 = 4116MB.
They match.

#### Others

Caches: Standby+Modified Mem (which is available)

**Hint**: you can use `Task Manager->Performance->Memory` to detect all memory (8GB).