# Windows Task Manager Memory resource values in percents and values do not match

Tags: windows, windows-10, task-manager, windows-11

I have 8GB RAM in my Windows 11 PC. The screenshot below shows that chrome is using about 800MB of RAM which is around 10% of the total RAM installed (800MB is around 10% of 8GB). But after I right click in the Task Manager window and change the Resource values of Memory from values to percents, it shows that chrome is using about 20% Memory as in the second screenshot.

[image]
[image]

Why does Task Manager think that 800MB is 20% of 8GB? I am aware that Task Manager shows approximate values but approximation does not mean that values can become twice as much.

I am using the latest release of Windows 11 right now and there are no updates available, but this problem was present even in Windows 10.

Comment: This question has been asked multiple times, the simple answer is just: Yes they do not match may be because they are computed from different values (the memory usage of a process has multiple different values depending on how you calculate). See also https://superuser.com/questions/1408639/task-manager-shows-only-50-of-ram-usage?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RAM usage % on Task Manager lower than actual RAM](https://superuser.com/questions/1278009/ram-usage-on-task-manager-lower-than-actual-ram)